# Do 4 batteries capable of outputting 0.5 A in parallel give the batteries a max output of 2 A?

Tags: power-supply, maximum-ratings

Sorry for the long question, but I couldn't think of another way to word it.

I'm working on a bicycle modification that requires 12 Volts, 4 Amps of power to run. I don't really want to buy a $80 car battery, and a low battery life is fine for this modification, so I was thinking of using a lot of AA batteries instead. From my calculations, it would take a minimum of 24 AA batteries to give that amount of power for one hour. But the problem is that my calculations assume that the capacity not only doubles, but so does the max output of the battery of batteries, something which I am not sure is true.

Comment: Just curious. But have you looked into RC hybrid Lipo batteries? The issue will be utility of their operating voltage over their discharge cycle while delivering your current. In standard packs, they will be quite able to deliver the current you need and very likely also the total energy storage. They provide excellent energy density, too. And with the high volume produced for the RC business, the pricing is good. You will have to deal with voltage droop for most technologies, so these may not present any unique problems there. As I said, just curious if you've looked into it, at all.

Answer (score 2):

If batteries are in parallel then the max output current adds for each battery.  For example if 4 batteries of 0.5A are placed in parallel then the total output current becomes 2A.

When batteries are put in series their output voltage adds but the current does not add.  For example four 1.5V, 0.5A batteries placed in series will give you a 6V 0.5A battery.

Batteries can be placed in combinations of series and parallel at the same time.  For example, you can make a string of eight 1.5V 0.5A AA batteries in series to make a 12V 0.5A battery string.  You can then place eight of those 12V 0.5A strings in parallel to increase the output current to 4A.  So you would need 64 AA alkaline batteries total.

Note that note that ordinary alkaline AA batteries generally have pretty high internal resistance (0.25 to 0.5 ohms).  They are usually not suitable for driving heavy loads.  NiMh AA batteries can have resistances of only milliohms and are suitable for driving loads of several amps.

From your post what you really need is a 12V battery that can output 4A for 1 hour (4Ah).

You can get a 12V 5Ah lead acid battery on Digikey for $27, which is probably cheaper than buying 64AA batteries.

BP5-12-T2    Battery, 12V, lead Acid, 5Ah

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/b-b-battery/BP5-12-T2/522-1010-ND/653331

Please note that if two batteries are placed in parallel they must be the same voltage.  Otherwise one battery will try to charge the other.  In the most benign case it would mean that you loose some energy.  In the worst case the batteries could be destroyed or explode.

What this means practically is that you should only place identical fully charged batteries in parallel.  A discharged battery even if identical to another battery will have a lower output voltage than a charged one.

Answer (score 0):

You have a capacity problem as well as a current problem : you need 4Ah.

Proper D cells (NiCd or NiMH) offer that sort of capacity (if you avoid the cheater 1.2Ah cells in a larger can!).

At 4A, (1C rate) capacity will be reduced a bit below this, but it's a better option than paralleling AA cells.

This allows you to use traditional battery holders and chargers for separate cells.

Alternatives such as LiPo batteries for radio controlled models, or small sealed Lead-Acid batteries work too, with the correct charger.